# Output without html tags, php

Tags: php

i have a simple php example

```
<?php
$txt = "<p>Hello world!</p>";

echo "<span>$txt</span>";
?>
```

How i can render the $text varibale without `p` elements, output should be like this:

```
<span>Hello world!</span>
```

Comment: echo `strip_tags($txt)` , Demo [click here](https://ideone.com/gQY8D9)

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, by removing the `<p>` tag from your code?

Comment: @Noman thank you saved me

Comment: @arkascha this is just an example from a project, i cant do this because its not part of my work i mean i cant access to databse to change varibiales.

Comment: Sure, we suspected something like that. Please specify such important information in your questions. How else do you expect a precise answer if you do not name the requirements?

Comment: @arkascha the question is clearly, i mean  if i can remove the `<p>` tag from my code, i'll not ask :)

Comment: Obviously it was not clear, since there are 4 confirmation ticks to my comment...

Comment: Ah, so a question is clear if only a minority of readers understand it. OK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `strip_tags()` or take the `<p>`'s out manually...